# Weird sed greedy regex behavior

Tags: regex, sed, greedy

I am trying to understand the behavior of sed wrt this regex: 
`sed -n "s/.*Directory \([^>]*\)>/\1/p" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*`

The goal here is to list the path to the webroot of all the enabled virtual hosts in Apache2.

The weird thing is that the result of this sample command:  
`sed -n "s/.*Directory \([^>]*\)>/\1/p" <<< "<Directory /var/www/my_site>"` is as expected: `/var/www/my_site`

But the result of `sed -n "s/.*Directory \([^>]*\)/\1/p" <<< "<Directory /var/www/my_site>"` is : `/var/www/my_site>`

**I know that the difference is the presence of `>`. The question is why is it necessary to add `>` to obtain the correct output ? `[^>]*` should be able to match everything and stop at `>` thus not capturing it in the parentheses.**

I don't understand why the '>' character is caught in the first command and not in the second one.
`[^>]` should have excluded '>' from the capturing parentheses...

Comment: 1st command has `>` in search term but 2nd one doesn't have it.

Comment: I know that. The question is why is it necessary to add `>` to obtain the correct output ? `[^>]*` should be able to match everything and stop at `>` thus not capturing it in the parentheses.

Comment: You aren't matching the `>` in the second command, so it isn't included in the replacement and stays the same. You are replacing the `([^>]*\)` with itself, the rest of the line is unchanged.If you just want whats in the brackets add `.*` to the end of the command outside of the brackets.

Comment: It does include it but doesn't have anything to stop at so it shows you everything until the end - in this case the >.

Comment: @A.Danischewski, actually check my comment to Kent's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your first line, you replace the **whole string** by the things in your group1:

so you got:
/var/www/my_site

in your 2nd line, you replace `<Directory......site` **Note, not whole string, the ending `>` was not there** with the same capture group. but the ending `>` was kept untouched. So you see it in output.

another example:

```
$ sed -n "s/fo*\([^o]*\)/\1/p" <<< "foooooowhatever this ooo will leave behind" 
whatever this ooo will leave behind
```

In above example, the target to replace is: `foooooowhatever this` the replacement is `whatever this` the rest string will be untouched.

Comment: Makes sense :)
Sed is not overwriting the `>` (as I asked for with the s/// command) because the regex will not match it if I do not explicitly put it in the said regex.

Comment: Yea, what happens is if you put a labeled hold \\( \\) and put other matching regex outside all the things that match simply disappear when you replace and reference the labeled hold like \1

Answer (score 1):

1st command has `>` in search term but 2nd one doesn't have it.

`[^>]*` matches everything **before** a `>` is matched (not including `>`) hence `>` remains in your 2nd sed command which is:

```
sed -n "s/.*Directory \([^>]*\)/\1/p"
```

Also note in first command:

```
sed -n "s/.*Directory \([^>]*\)>/\1/p"
```

`\1` is not capturing `>` but your sed command is omitting it in replacement.

Comment: See updated answer, I have already answered your comment i.e. `[^>]*` matches everything before a `>` is found in both commands. So `\1` is all the text just before `>`. Only in 1st command you have `>` hence it is omitted in final output.

Comment: I am accepting Kent's answer because he provided an example, and he actually was clearer to my understanding.
Besides you have nearly three times as much rep as he has, so please don't be mad at me for letting him have the cookies :)

Comment: @mak: Not at all, it is always OP's prerogative to accept any answer.